# MySQL Error:#1238 - Variable 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout' is a read only variable

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I am using MySQL version:5.1.73

I want to change  `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` mysql variable.

```sql
set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
#1238 - Variable 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout' is a read only variable
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of Mysql you are using ? it seems there is a bug in Mysql version lower than 5.5 [Mysql Bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71043)

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I am using MySQL version:5.1.73

Answer (score 2):

[`innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable in MySQL 5.1 is **not dynamic**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout), so you must specify it on command line when starting server:

```
 mysqld --innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
```

or in the [configuration file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) (my.cnf, my.ini):

```
[mysqld]
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
```

restart MySQL server after configuration file change.